Showing the Bookmark Panel in Spotifre using IronPython
I am currently trying to create a button that will show a popover of the Bookmark Panel on the screen when clicked. I have working code below that will do this for the FilterPanel but need to change this to the BookmarkPanel. There is no attribute BookmarkPanel in the library so would great appreciate if someone could help me with this issue.
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Layout import PanelState
filterPanel = Document.ActivePageReference.FilterPanel

if filterPanel.PanelState == PanelState.Popover:
    filterPanel.PanelState = PanelState.Docked 
    filterPanel.Visible=False
else: #show udocked filterpanel
    filterPanel.PanelState = PanelState.Popover

